# Color sliding hover should continue moving the save direction when hover-out

Tags: css, vue.js, hover, nuxt.js, gradient

The task is to make a hover effect on some list element. When mouse-over - gradient fills list element with some color from top to bottom; but when mouse-leave - gradient should continue its moving from top to bottom. With simple hover effect it always moves backways.

I use Vue and Nuxt, I want to make it on pure CSS but it seems to me its not possible. How to do it?

https://codepen.io/nosdmitry/pen/zYZgNQp

```
.test {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.test::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}

.test:hover::before {
  -webkit-transition: border-radius 2s;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}
```

My code with gradient:

```
.test {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.test::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-position: bottom;
}

.test:hover::before {
  background-position: top;
}
```

Comment: there is no gradient in your code, did you mean color sliding ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, my fault, https://codepen.io/nosdmitry/pen/zYZgNQp here is with gradient. But it doesn't matter what to use, it moves back anyway

Comment: still not a gradient, even if you used linear-gradient, it's a solid color so what is your final result? a color sliding OR you will have a real gradient?

Comment: @TemaniAfif The final result is color sliding.

Comment: so update your question to make it clear

Answer (score 1):

Do it like below:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid;
  background: linear-gradient(blue 0 0) top/100% 0 no-repeat;
  transition:0.5s, background-position 0s 0.5s;
}

.box:hover {
  background-size:100% 100%;
  background-position:bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it is almost the think than I want!

Comment: But when you hover button and immediately remove the mouse - color slides back. Ho to make full animation with no interruption? So it should always fills div with color till it's bottom no metter how long the mouse was on it...